# Apply CSS styles on html tags after create them dynamically (inside .ts file)

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add DIV after the project run (add it dynamically) but the problem is it didn't take the CSS style that I've set to it.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat2',
  templateUrl: './chat2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat2.component.css']
})
export class Chat2Component implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  messages = [];
  totalOnline = 0;
  user = 1;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    const divMessages: HTMLDivElement = document.querySelector(".msg_history");
    let m = document.createElement("div");
    m.innerHTML =
        `<div class="incoming_msg">
        <div class="incoming_msg_img" > <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
        <div class="received_msg">
          <div class="received_withd_msg">
            <p>Abdulaziz Burghal , Hello from Chat</p>
            <span class="time_date"> 4:53 AM    |    June 9</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>`;
      divMessages.appendChild(m);
    divMessages.scrollTop = divMessages.scrollHeight;
  }



}
```

**Note: div that I've created it inside HTML file took the CSS style without any problem .**

So, how could apply the CSS style on div's that I'll create them by code

Update:

Added CSS

```
.incoming_msg_img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6%;
}
.received_msg {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 92%;
 }
 .received_withd_msg p {
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #646464;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Update 2**

when I add the CSS styles as inline style it's work but the problem is the Div that contains the image it's CSS doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you use angular way to fill your list the CSS will work:**

HTML

```
<div class="inbox_chat">
                <div class="chat_list active_chat" *ngFor="let userData of listOfUsers">
                  <div class="chat_people">
                    <div class="chat_ib">
                      <h5>{{userData.userName}} <span class="chat_date">{{userData.creationDate}}</span></h5>
                      <p>{{userData.messageText}}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

TypeScript part:

```
   listOfUsers: Array<InboxChatBoxDto> = [];// define it gloably


fillInboxChat(){
  this._messageService
  .inboxChat()
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      //alert("finished")
      //finishedCallback();
    })
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {

    this.listOfUsers=result;

    // });

  });

}
```

**If you use javascript to build your HTML you need to use an inline CSS property:**
HTML part

```
<div class="inbox_chat"></div>
```

TypeScript part (use javascript code within it):

```
fillInboxChat(){
  this._messageService
  .inboxChat()
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      //alert("finished")
      //finishedCallback();
    })
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {





    const divMessages: HTMLDivElement = document.querySelector(".inbox_chat");


    result.forEach((item,index)=>{

      let m = document.createElement("div");
      m.className="chat_list"
      m.style.cssText=` border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 18px 16px 10px;`

      m.innerHTML = `<div class="chat_people" style='overflow:hidden; clear:both;' >
      <div class="chat_ib" (click)="fillMessageHistory(`+item.userId+`)">
        <h5 style='font-size:15px; color:#464646; margin:0 0 8px 0;'>` + item.userName +`<span class="chat_date" style='font-size:13px; float:right;'>`+  moment(item.creationTime ).format('YYYY/MM/ddd')   +`</span></h5>
        <p style='font-size:14px; color:#989898; margin:auto'>`+ item.messageText+`</p>
      </div>
    </div>`;

    divMessages.appendChild(m);





    });

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the css in a few ways.

#### Via css

It's not clear why the css style isn't working, if you post it we can probably help more. Are you targeting the div or class of your dynamicly created html in the css?

#### Dynamically in JS

You'll have to get the element in JavaScript, either by using the `m` element you have or attaching a unique id to one of your elements.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("${unique id})
```

Then you can set the style

```js
el.style.cssText = "${your style text}"
```